# borrow function from `less.js`

Tags: javascript, less

I want to use the `lighten()` function from `less.js` but not sure how to get it to work. I copy the functions I needed from `less.js`into my own js file:

```
var Color = function (rgb, a, originalForm) {
    //
    // The end goal here, is to parse the arguments
    // into an integer triplet, such as `128, 255, 0`
    //
    // This facilitates operations and conversions.
    //
    if (Array.isArray(rgb)) {
        this.rgb = rgb;
    } else if (rgb.length == 6) {
        this.rgb = rgb.match(/.{2}/g).map(function (c) {
            return parseInt(c, 16);
        });
    } else {
        this.rgb = rgb.split('').map(function (c) {
            return parseInt(c + c, 16);
        });
    }
    this.alpha = typeof a === 'number' ? a : 1;
    if (typeof originalForm !== 'undefined') {
        this.value = originalForm;
    }
};

Color.prototype.toHSL = function () {
    var r = this.rgb[0] / 255,
        g = this.rgb[1] / 255,
        b = this.rgb[2] / 255,
        a = this.alpha;

    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2, d = max - min;

    if (max === min) {
        h = s = 0;
    } else {
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);

        switch (max) {
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2;               break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4;               break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }
    return { h: h * 360, s: s, l: l, a: a };
};
```

Then I create a function to use them:

```
function lighten(color, amount, method){
    var hsl = color.toHSL();

        if (typeof method !== "undefined" && method.value === "relative") {
            hsl.l +=  hsl.l * amount.value / 100;
        }
        else {
            hsl.l += amount.value / 100;
        }
        hsl.l = clamp(hsl.l);
        return hsla(hsl);
}
```

I get this error message:

> Error: color.toHSL is not a function. (In 'color.toHSL()',
>   'color.toHSL' is undefined)

Any Idea how to get this to work?

Comment: What are you passing as the `color` argument? It will need to be a `Color` object to have the `.toHSL` method

Comment: It also needs to be defined using the `new` operator, ie `new Color(....)`

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair: better late than never ... see OP's 106 other questions :P

Comment: Apart from the `new Color()` that are mentioned in earlier comments, you are missing a lot of other helper functions and objects (like `colorFunctions`, `Dimension`, `clamp`, `hsla`, `number` etc). There are a lot of stuff that needs to be copied which would eventually make it easier for you to write your own simple function by just adopting the algorithm (subject to copyright stuff).

Comment: I found a work around for this issue. I ended up use [TinyColor](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor). It have most of the color feature from `less.js`.